# Is it possible to have Double Secondary Navigation?

Tags: css

Is it even possible to have 2 different displays of the same secondary navigation on a menu?

For instance my client wants to have a horizontal main nav...with a horizontal secondary nav and ALSO a drop down secondary nav - both with the same nav links.

I ask, because they want a tertiary nav that appears horizontally OVER the horizontal sub nav.  If that happens though, the user will NOT have a way to get back to the horizontal secondary nav to choose a different link unless they have a different way of getting to it.  Hence the dropdown secondary nav.

I know... crazy.  If I could get a definitive answer that there is NOT an easy way to get 2 secondary navs to appear at the same time, then I go back to my client with that answer.

I hope my explanation wasn't too confusing.

Comment: Fired from the same event (such as, a `mouseover`)? It's not impossible, but seems a bit... confusing.

Comment: Can you demonstrate with some images? (If you can't, it's possible it's not worth coding.)

Comment: (*And, btw, if it's a paying client, they are never wrong, just sometimes... mistaken, or too cutting edge.*)

Comment: it's possible to do that with javascript but the original idea seems suspect, IMO it will be too confusing for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than start with code, I would start with building a mockup.

I have found as a entrepreneur and a developer, mockups are mandatory. This is especially true of my own projects. I think I know what the UI will look like. However, once the mockup is done by the UI designer, sometimes I discover I didn't really like the result.

I now tell my UI designer to mockup what he thinks I am describing before we build live code. If we have a disagreement, I ask him to show me rather than tell me.

About half the time, the mockup demonstrates that the UI designer misunderstood what I was asking for.

Do a mockup. Get clarification. Then worry about the code.